# less scrolling issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, less

I am working through a linux training book on a fresh raspberry pi install (Debian v10.0) and have noticed an issue when using `less /etc/passwd`.

when using the keyboard controls to scroll down, it goes beyond the bottom of the list and prints multiple lines of ~, and then it will not allow me to scroll back up.

Running `less /etc/group`, keyboard scrolling functions normally

Keyboard controls also function normally when using less in a pipe such as `ls --help | less`

Comment: What does `echo "LESS=$LESS"` tell you, please?

Comment: @roaima returns `"LESS="`

Comment: Your keyboard controls - was this specifically `G` (capital G) to jump to the end of the file?

Comment: no, i was using pageup/pagedown, or the up/down arrow keys. It seems it was an overlooked error on my part, that @sudodus answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the normal behaviour, when there are less lines in the file than in the terminal window. (It happens to me too, and the **`~`** characters are 'spacefillers'). In this case there is no scrolling because the whole file is displayed.

Comment: it looks like this might be the case. I guess i overlooked that fact since all the text scrolled so quickly up the screen